# Remove lines in Picker XAMARIN

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Please, help me to remove lines in the picker.I tried SelectionDividerHeight=0,but I have the error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove lines you can use this function and make color Transparent
[Change color lines in Picker XAMARIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560609/change-color-lines-in-picker-xamarin?noredirect=1#comment112394951_63560609)

Comment: You can mark this answer later so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: I will do it. But I must wait 11 hours

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build this with Xamarin.Native Android, and you are using a `NumberPicker` or `DatePicker`, it is an easy solution: `picker.ShowDividers = ShowDividers.None;` But if you are using the Xamarin.Forms picker, there is no property you can use to hide the separator, as you can see in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/). So you have to use a CustomRenderer.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622535/how-do-i-style-the-items-list-in-a-xamarin-picker-in-android)'s an example of how to create a custom renderer for a Xamarin.Forms Picker and use it in your code.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers)'s another good resource for Xamarin.Android native pickers

Comment: I have my CustomPicker and I used NumberPicker,but picker.ShowDividers = ShowDividers.None; did not help me

Comment: Please share the code of the CustomPicker that is overriding the behavior. It's probably in your adapter