# Change color lines in Picker XAMARIN

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have my CustomPicker.Please tell me how I can change the line`s color in Picker window
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change the colour of the line below / Border of a TextBox (Entry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207168/is-it-possible-to-change-the-colour-of-the-line-below-border-of-a-textbox-ent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement it by using **reflection**  .

```
private void setNumberPickerDividerColor(TextColorNumberPicker numberPicker)
    {


        TextColorNumberPicker picker = numberPicker;
        Java.Lang.Reflect.Field[] pickerFields = 
        Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(NumberPicker)).GetDeclaredFields();
        foreach (Java.Lang.Reflect.Field pf in pickerFields)
        {
            if (pf.Name.Equals("mSelectionDivider"))
            {
                pf.Accessible = true;
                pf.Set(picker, new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Red));

            }
        }
    }
```

And invoked it after calling **SetDisplayedValues**

```
if (model.Items != null && model.Items.Any())
{
   // set style here

   picker.MaxValue = model.Items.Count - 1;
   picker.MinValue = 0;


   picker.SetDisplayedValues(model.Items.ToArray());
   picker.WrapSelectorWheel = false;
   picker.Value = model.SelectedIndex;

}
setNumberPickerDividerColor(picker);
```

[image]